# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - purple screen - unusual circumstances

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a machine containing a nVidia GeForce GTX 1650. It booted up fine in the store where I got the machine from, and tried it out a bit before taking it home. At home, GRUB loads, but when I selected "Ubuntu", it hangs on a purple screen (ie: it does not reach the login screen).

The "advanced options for Ubuntu" provides four options, two of them "recovery mode" which print out text but hangs on the "Loading initial ramdisk ...". Pressing e on the GRUB menu and adding NOMODESET does not do a thing.

I have a live DVD and pressed a key when the icons appear, giving me a list of options that do nothing,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: No, I am afraid that page does not help me. I tried everything, even messing around with the UEFI settings in my BIOS, adding nomodeset and acpi=off to the linux line. And I can't disable Secure Boot. As for the nvidia drivers, how am I supposed to install them without an Internet connection?

Comment: Accidentally plugging the VGA cable into the monitor triggered the purple screen, but Linux has set some sort of flag in my BIOS that prevent Ubuntu from loading or booting into the installation program.